# Definition of Locally Convex Curve

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

I am looking for the definition of a locally convex curve  but I cannot find it.

Please could you give me a book on differential geometry that gives this 
definition and some properties?

To be more precise the curve is a map $ \gamma: I \subset \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n.$ I know the definition of a convex curve but the locally convex curve I can't find.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Everywhen you define something locally it just means that it is defined in a neighbourhood of a point. In this case it means that a curve satisfies the definition of convexity in a neighbourhood of a point

Comment: thanks, @Nicolò   for example for the planar curve $\gamma $  this means the trace of $\gamma$ lies on one side of the closed half-plane determined by the tangent line at $t$ this don't make sense locally? what do you think

Comment: If you consider the curve restricted to a neigbourhood $U_t$ of a point $t$, i.e. $\gamma : U_t \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n $ this makes perfectly sense. Indeed this is just the definition of convexity for the restricted curve

Comment: thanks @Nicolò now it is clear